# command diffp: index on a variable for partial derivative bug?

Tags: math-mode, packages

Consider the following, with the package:

```
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}

$\diffp*{A}{k}{Q_L}>0$
```

The code compiles.

However with:

```
$\diffp*{A}{Q_L}{k}>0$
```

It returns me "A left brace was mandatory here..."

Why so ? Isn't it possible with this package to have variables with index ?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, `esdiff` scans the second argument to `\diffp` in order to compute automatically the order of the derivative.

Since `Q_L` has three tokens, this makes `esdiff` think to a third order derivative with respect to `Q`, `_` and `L`; errors ensue.

Just brace the “composite” variable to make `\diffp` consider it as a single object:

```
$\diffp*{A}{{Q_L}}{k}>0$
```

Answer (score 2):

My it is only an humble alternative to your used old [package](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/esdiff/esdiff.pdf) → `esdiff` (*Writing derivatives*, Eddie Saudrais, April 24, 2008). There are also two recent packages to write the derivates (of type classic or partial):

**1)** `diffcoeff` package with a simple syntax;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}

Using \textit{diffcoeff} package:
\[\diffp A{Q_L}[k]>0\]
```

[image]

**2)** The `derivative` package of Simon Jensen, v. 0.98 of 2020/07/20.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
Using \textit{derivative} package:
\[\pdv{A}{Q_L}_{k}>0\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In both cases you can get the same result of `esdiff`.